# Routes: Make routes conditional based on configuration setting from application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, conditional-statements

How would one make ruby on rails routes conditional based on a settings from the application?  Im using an APP_CONFIG["myvar"] to globally setup values ( gets loaded true initialiser )

Now in my routes I want to swap certain routes based on this. To be precise I have a beta signup form that I want to show when the APP_CONFIG["my app"] is true. Else I want the homage of my app to route to home#index

Havent been able to just use if statement in my routes , it breaks the routing

Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest using controller logic to do this, setup a partial which is rendered when APP_CONFIG["my app"] returns true else just render the action template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to disable route, try to use :constraints property in routes definition, like:

```
resources :users, :constraints => lambda { |request| APP_CONFIG["my app"].present? }
```